# Differentiable proofs

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Show that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is such that $-x^2\le f(x)\le x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

Really confused because isnt 0 the only soltion.  and How would I apply the definition of differentiable to this?

Comment: What do you mean "0 is the only solution"? What the inequality says is just that the curve $y=f(x)$ lies between the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$, and there are many such functions.

Comment: My bad I did not really get what was being asked

Answer (score 2):

Let $h \neq 0$ be small and note that the given inequality implies that $f(0) = 0$ (take $x=0$ in the inequality). Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{f(h)}{h}.
\end{align*}
Since $-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$ implies $|f(x)| \leq x^2$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\left\vert\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}\right\vert = \left\vert\frac{f(h)}{h} \right\vert
\leq \frac{h^2}{|h|} = |h| \to 0
\end{align*}
as $h \to 0$. By definition of the derivative, we see that $f^\prime(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: So being greater then -x^2 wont have a effect on the h you output?

Comment: @JJBurt Having that $-x^2 \leq f(x) \leq x^2$ tells us that $|f(x)| \leq x^2$. This is exactly what is needed for the argument

Comment: @JJBurt When working with limits, it is generally much more helpful to have both an upper and a lower bound for the function!